# Error Logs from Python .exe

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I am new to programming on Windows and Python (mainly macOS / Ruby). I am writing a program that scans IP addresses, finds networked devices, logs into them, and then upgrades their firmware. I wrote a Python script to do this and used Tkinter for the GUI. When I run the script in python, everything works as expected. However, I am having issues when I run the script after I create the .exe from PyInstaller.

When I try to "map the network" and export the output to XML using python-nmap I think it's throwing an error. I have a scan_network() function on a thread and I check to see if its running, and when its done I get a popup saying "XML Generated". When I input the IPs into the GUI it almost immediately tells me the XML is generated, alas no XML.

I am assuming there was a problem with nmap not being bundled into exe, or something, I am not sure. Is there a way I can add a way to check logs?

Here is the function that the button "Scan Network" calls. How can I add logs to this?

```
 import nmap

 def scan_network(ips):
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()

    nm.scan(hosts=ips, arguments='-v -A')
        with open('xml/pyscan.xml', 'w') as xml_file:
            xml_file.write(nm.get_nmap_last_output())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more research.

This works!

```
import nmap
import traceback
from utils import xml_parser

def scan_network(ips):
    try:
        nm = nmap.PortScanner()

        nm.scan(hosts=ips, arguments='-v -A')
        with open('xml/pyscan.xml', 'w') as xml_file:
            xml_file.write(nm.get_nmap_last_output())

        xml_parser.parse_xml('xml/pyscan.xml')
    except:
        f = open('nmap.log', 'w')
        e = traceback.format_exc()
        f.write(str(e))
        f.close()
```